Quantum Master Equation for Damped Harmonic Oscillator
In the book, Statistical Methods in Quantum Optics Volume 1, while writing the master equation for the damped harmonic oscillator system, I am not able to understand how the system operators S1 and S2 are transformed into interaction picture. The book mentions that, it is the solution to the Heisenberg equation of motion but it is unclear to me.
Please help me understand how the following can be shown,


Expand exponents into the Taylor series, next start to compute commutators like $[a,a^{\dagger}a]$ and etc. You will see the structure. It is the application of Baker-Hausdorff formula: if $[A,B]$ commutes with $A$ and $B$ then $\exp(A)\exp(B)=\exp(A+B+[A,B]/2)$

Define the operator $$S(t)=e^{iHt} a\, e^{-iHt} \tag{1} \label{1} $$ with $$H= \omega_0 a^\dagger a \quad \text{and} \quad  [a,a^\dagger]=\mathbf{1}. \tag{2}$$
Differentiating eq. \eqref{1} with respect to the parameter $t$ yields $$   \frac{d S(t)}{dt}= i e^{iHt} \underbrace{[H,a]}_{- \omega_0 a} e^{-iHt}=-i \omega_0 S(t). \tag{3}$$ The solution of the differential equation $dS(t)/dt=-i\omega_0 S(t)$ with the initial condition $S(0)=a$ (cf. eq. \eqref{1} for $t=0$) is given by $$S(t)=ae^{-i\omega_0t}, \tag{4} \label{4}$$ showing the desired result. Taking the adjoint of eq. \eqref{4}, gives $$S^\dagger(t)=e^{iHt}a^\dagger e^{-iHt}=a^\dagger e^{i \omega_0t}. \tag{5}$$
